# Print NSLocalizedString key instead of value

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

I need to print the keys of Localizable.strings in my App, instead of their values (for a debugging purpose). Is there a fast way to override the NSLocalizedString() method or redefine the macro, something like:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) NSLocalizedString(key, key)
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52236844/1801544 ?

Comment: Nope. I really need to show all the keys on my App, because the request that I got from a superior, was to "tell" him all the keys that I used and where. It's like an impossibile task to do manually, so I got the idea to run the App with the keys instead of the values

Comment: Maybe you could look for solutions on how to find unused keys, and compare with the list of all your keys. The disjoint between the two should give you the key. I don't know though how it works when keys are computed. Like "key_" and then `"key_" + "1"`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to export your app for localizations via Product Menu > Export Localizations within Xcode, then save the xcloc file to your Desktop.

After which you could use a python script to parse the inner xliff (xml) to find the file elements with `original` attributes which contain `Localizable.strings` and print the `trans-unit`'s `source` element text within the body of them. Here's an example of a python script which should do it localizationKeys.py:

```
import sys
import os.path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import argparse as ap
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
    # filename argument ex: de.xliff
    parser.add_argument('filename', help="filename of the xliff to find keys ex:de.xliff")
    # verbose flag
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', default=False, help='Show all the output')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if (os.path.isfile(args.filename)):
        tree = et.parse(args.filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
        match = re.match(r'\{.*\}', root.tag)
        ns = match.group(0) if match else ''
        files = root.findall(ns + 'file')
        for file in files:
            originalAttr = file.attrib['original']
            # find all files which contain Localizable.strings
            if originalAttr != None and 'Localizable.strings' in originalAttr:
                if args.verbose == True:
                    print("----- Localizations for file: " + originalAttr + " -----")
                # grab the body element
                bodyElement = file.find(ns + 'body')
                # get all the trans-units
                transUnits = bodyElement.findall(ns + 'trans-unit')
                for transUnit in transUnits:
                    # print all the source values (keys)
                    print(transUnit.find(ns + 'source').text)
    else:
        print("No file found with the specified name: " + args.filename)
```

Which you could then use as follows:

```
python3 localizationKeys.py en.xcloc/Localized\ Contents/en.xliff
```

Or if you'd prefer to print to to a file instead

```
python3 localizationKeys.py en.xcloc/Localized\ Contents/en.xliff > output.txt
```

This could almost definitely be more concise using `xpath` instead, but this is just what I came up with quickly.

Comment: Hi R4N. Thanks for your script, but I need something that replace the values with the keys because I need to run my App showing the keys in the labels instead of their values. 

I don't know if this script can help but for what I'm understanding it is doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I obtained what I needed

```
// Overriding NSLocalizedString to print keys instead of values
#ifdef NSLocalizedString
#undef NSLocalizedString
#endif
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) key
```

In this way the App use the keys instead of the values